# Best strategy: Deploy new code to existing instances or new ones?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, digital-ocean

Thoughts wanted: When deploying new code, are there benefits to deploying to brand new instances (droplets on Digital Ocean) versus deploying to existing instances?

With the ease of deploying new instances nowadays, I'm wondering if the better route to go now is to simply deploy a new instance and change the routing to the new instance...

I know that whether you use Chef or other deployment tool may dictate a solution, but looking for the general thoughts on the topic....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on how big your infrastructure is and how much work you will need to debug your system in the case of show stoppers and bugs. deploying to existing machines on a small scale can be maintained to some extent but when the footprint of your system becomes big, it should be time for [Immutable infrastructure](http://blog.codeship.com/immutable-infrastructure/) ; where you are deploying new machines and getting rid of the old ones. instead of the approach of applying new changes on existing ones.

The benefits of this approach are:

1. Easier more capsulated deployments on the machine level. you attach the new instances, wait for traffic to stop on the old ones and then take them off.
2. Logging is more centralized for all your machines, that is handy in the case of debugging; *where the issue is coming from*, and *which machine is creating this bad behaviour*.
3. Flexibility to kill servers that are giving problems and creating
   new ones on the fly to connect them to your load balancer.

Comment: Awesome answer. Did not realize the concept existed, so pointing me in the right direction helped immensely. Further study is need, but I think I'll start with centralizing my log files and work from there.

Comment: Watching Chad Fowler talk about the concept. Fascinating. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DVSNsAei0VE